# SUMO sim time and real time difference

Tags: sumo

I used traci.simulation.getTime to get the current sim time of SUMO.
However, this time runs faster than real time.

For example, when sim time grow from 0-100, real time just grow from 0-20.

How can I make SUMO simulation time be the same with real time?

I tried --step-length = 1, but this didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `--step-length` property is a value in seconds describing the length of one simulation step. If you put a higher number here vehicles have less time to react, but your simulation probably runs faster.
For the real time issue you might have a look to the [sumo-user mailinglist](https://www.eclipse.org/lists/sumo-user/msg00750.html). I think the mail gives a pretty good answer to your issue:

> the current limit to the real time factor is the speed of your
>   computer. If you want to slow the GUI down you can change the delay
>   value (which is measured in milliseconds) so a value of 100 would add
>   100ms to every simulation step (if you simulation is small and runs
>   with the default step length of 1s this means factor 10). If you want
>   to speed it up, run without GUI or buy a faster computer ;-).

To check how close your simulation is to wall clock time, you can check the [generated output](http://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/Simulation/Output) from SUMO. The thing you're looking for is called *Real time factor*